# ruby-on-rails: update_attributes overrides model validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I have a typical, Post model:

```
class Post< ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :user_id                                   #Line 1
    validates_presence_of :title,:body                               #Line 2
```

in the controller, I have:

```
def create
   if request.post? 
       if login_required
           @post = Post.new(params[:post])                            #Line 3
           @post .update_attribute("user_id",session[:userid])        #Line 4
```

However, if the validations on Line 2 fail the Post will still be created, unless Line 4 is commented out.

1) Why?

2) Suggestions on a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the entry on `update_attribute` in [the doc for ActiveRecord::Persistence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute):

> Updates a single attribute and saves
>   the record without going through the
>   normal validation procedure. This is
>   especially useful for boolean flags on
>   existing records.

Seems like it's a loophole to help you avoid the overhead of validation when you make a quickie tweak to a record.  If you want validation, just use

```
@post.update_attributes(:user_id => session[:userid])
```